# Adding a hash prefix at the config phase if it's missing

Tags: angularjs, seo, phantomjs, google-crawlers

I am now integrating phantom in my Angularjs-based web application.

[This](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html) fine article says that I should call the `$locationProvider.hashPrefix()` method to set the prefix to '!' from SEO reasons(allow crawlers to intercept the `_escaped_fragment` component of the URL).

The problem is that I haven't though of the earlier, and some of my URLs look as following:
`#/home`.

I though perhaps there is a way that I can implant this '!' char into the begging of the URL programmatically(in case it is not already there) at the config function of the APP, instead having to edit a lot of markup manually.

Comment: What "markup" would you have to edit manually?  Do you have a lot of hard-coded urls somewhere?

Comment: I've had a similar issue. Currently I see this error when I use the wrong prefix. 'Error: Invalid url  "some url" missing hash prefix "#!".' For users that have links to the old url scheme it would be great to be able to handle the error or for the router to use the otherwise function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had similar problem and manually (search/replace) went through all the links and fixed them.

The other problem I had was the external sites were using the old format i.e.
http://plinkplink.net/#/event/3
instead of the new format
http://plinkplink.net/#!/event/3

The fix I did for that is not strictly speaking angularjs idiomatic but it does the job. I've added this script to the header of my page. It simply redirects pages with # to pages with #!:

```
    <script>
        var loc = window.location.href
        if (loc.indexOf("#") != -1 &&  loc.indexOf("#!") == -1 ){
            window.location.href = loc.replace("#", "#!");
        }
    </script>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is a possible solution, thank you for your answer.

P.S, you might want to apply the ngCloak directive to the title of your web page, this way browsers will index it more accurately, and audience won't see page.title() for an instance there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking to the # value?  ie - `<a href="#/my/page">`  If so, you shouldn't be.  You should be linking to the url without the # prefix and I believe it'll solve your issue.