# Angular: redirecting /#%21/ to /#!/

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

In emails that we send to users, we include links to Angular app like the following:

```
http://example.com/#!/mypage
```

We've noticed that some email clients or browsers, for one reason or another, upon click direct the user to this instead:

```
http://example.com/#%21/mypage
```

Angular then throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$location:ihshprfx] Invalid url "http://example.com/#%21/mypage", missing hash prefix "#!".
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.10/$location/ihshprfx
```

We are using `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');`.  I'm trying to find a way to detect instances where `$location` is `/#%21/` rather than `/#!/` and then redirect properly, but I can't find a way to detect and/or get Angular to do this.  What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finding a better answer here:

[Adding a hash prefix at the config phase if it's missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402028/adding-a-hash-prefix-at-the-config-phase-if-its-missing)

Using `$locationChangeStart` didn't work because angular threw the error during initialization, so `$locationChangeStart` was never tripped.

Instead, I went with the following approach:

```
<head>
  <!-- Change #%21 to #! on first load -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var loc = window.location.href;
      if (loc.indexOf('#%21') > -1 && loc.indexOf('#!') === -1 ) {
          window.location.href = loc.replace("#%21", "#!");
      }
  </script>

<!-- More stuff ... -->
</head>
<body>...
```

This (a) allows me to rewrite the URL before we ever hit Angular, and (b) makes sure we only rewrite it the first time the app is loaded, rather than any time there's a location change--just in case at some point in the future we deliberately write a change that includes a `#%21`.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most elegant way to go about solving your problem, but you could catch the `$locationChangeStart` event and then conditionally redirect the user with the `$location` service based on what the nature of the URL is.

For example:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work--the first time the page is loaded, angular throws the error before ever hitting `$locationChangeStart`